# SQL INNER JOIN mechanism

Tags: sql

Just wondering how INNER JOIN works internally. I have two test tables:

test1: id, field
test2: id, field

test1: (123, a) (123, b)
test2: (123, c) (123, d)

```
SELECT *
FROM test1 INNER JOIN
     test2
     ON test1.id = test2.id;
```

The result was:

```
a c
b c
a d
b d
```

But I was expecting:

```
a c
a d
b c
b d
```

I thought the query would select a record from left table, loop through right table for all matched record before move to the next record. Apparently it wasn't the case. Could anyone give me a quick tutorial on this one? Thx

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables -- and result sets -- represent *unordered* sets.  So, the two versions of your result set are the same, because they differ only in ordering.

If you want results in a particular order, you need to use `order by`.  Please remember that!

Comment: I would like to learn a bit more as to how the mechanism works internally. Are there loops involved when one table joins another or is it totally different algorithm?

Comment: @justin . . . You should start with the documentation for the database you are using.  But how the algorithms work (and there are many of them) really has no relevance to the ordering of the result set.  There is simply no guarantee of the order without `ORDER BY`.  Ever.